# python: open a json file in a different directory?

Tags: python, json

Here's my code:

```
import json    
with open("json.items") as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

It works fine when I move the json file into the same directory. However, I'm trying to get the json file from a different directory. How would I do that? This is what I have tried and its not working:

```
with open("/lowerfolder/json.items") as json_file:
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Depending on your platform, starting a path with `/` means absolute path from the root

Comment: Meaning a relative path should be `open("lowerfolder/json.items")` without the `/`

Comment: What @mhlester said, or alternatively `open('./lowerfolder/json.items')`, or use a full absolute path (e.g. `open('/home/strikepricer/files/lowerfolder/json.items')`).

Comment: What platform are you running the code? Mac, linux, or windows?

Comment: actually it worked! "lowerfolder/items.json" no / needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your platform, starting a path with `/` means absolute path from the root

Meaning a relative path should be `open("lowerfolder/json.items")` without the `/`

Comment: You should probably move the first paragraph (about whether this is good form) to a comment on your answer, or at the very least to a parenthetical at the end of the answer, instead of being at the very top. But otherwise, there's nothing wrong with your form. Most importantly, it's a good answer that will be useful to anyone with this problem, and you even expanded it from your original comment. And you're not trying to steal anyone else's credit or game the system. So… what could be wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks @abarnert. I've never done it before so I thought I'd check. It didn't seem to benefit anyone else; I hadn't thought of visitors from *the future* (hi future people!)

Comment: Always remember [Guido's time machine](http://wxpython.org/blog/2008/06/10/time-machine-saves-bacon/).